# Pointer Dereferencing: cannot convert ‘Node**’ to ‘Node*’

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm writing a code to insert an element, using call by reference. 
I cant figure out what this mess with pointers is. Please guide me as to whats wrong in my implementation.

My problem here is clearly conceptual so I'd appreciate if the explanation behind the answer is given, than the answer itself.

```
#include <iostream>
// Insert an element in a Single Linked List
using namespace std;

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
} Node;

void Insert(int x, Node* head);
int main()
{
    int n, x;
    cout<<"How many elements?\n";
    cin>>n;
    Node* head = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Insert Number\n";
        cin>>x;
        Insert(x, &head);
    }
    Print(head);
    return 0;
}
void Insert(int x, Node** phead) // Insert at the beginning
{
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = x; // (*temp).data = x
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (*phead != NULL) temp->next = *phead;
    *phead = temp;
}
```

The full error is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Node**’ to ‘Node*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void Insert(int, Node*)’
   Insert(x, &head);
```

Comment: Why do you declare an `Insert()` you never define?

Comment: Forward declaration of `void Insert(int x, Node* head);` does not match implementation of `void Insert(int x, Node** phead)`

Comment: Unrelated: might as well remove `temp->next = NULL;` and always `temp->next = *phead;`. If `*phead` is NULL, it effectively does `temp->next = NULL;` for you. If not, you get what you want anyway.

Comment: Also unrelated: Carrying the last comment through, if you add a `Node (int pdata, Node* pnext = NULL): data(pdata), next(pnext){}` constructor to `Node`, you can simplify `Insert` to `*phead = new Node(x, *phead);`

Comment: OT: `typedef struct Node` is C.

Comment: @user4581301: No need to define a constructor, aggregate-initialization will work great.

Comment: Good point. `Insert` now looks like `*phead = new Node{x, *phead};` and that's all you need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function prototype doesn't match the definition.

```
void Insert(int x, Node* head);
void Insert(int x, Node** phead)
{
```

Comment: I never saw the header. G++ was pointing me to the function instead. Good catch, Thank you!